# How to use netlink to monitor the kernel arp table in userspace deamon?

Tags: linux, sockets, netlink

I know we can use 'NETLINK_ROUTE' socket with RTM_F_NOTIFY flag to notify user if route changes according to the RFC3549. But I can't find one method to notify the user when arp table changes.

PS: I use linux kernel 3.0.6

Answer (score 3):

One should use `NETLINK_ROUTE` socket and `bind()` to the group `RTNLGRP_NEIGH`.

After that one can get `ndmsg` notifications with `recv()`. Pls note, that all notifications must be consumed, otherwise the socket will raise the `ENOBUF` exception with the next `recv()` after the overflow.

Or with external `ip(8)` utility:

```
$ ip monitor all    # get all the notifications
$ ip monitor neigh  # get only arp notifications
```

Or with a Python [library](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2):

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
from pprint import pprint

ip = IPRoute()
ip.bind()  # subscribe to all the events
while True:
    pprint(ip.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right - I would suggest you to analyse sources of "ip" program. When you run "ip monitor" and add or remove any ARP entry then "ip monitor" will show you appropriate message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of pure arp notifications but you could use the arpd which runs in user-space and is intended for cases where the arp table is very large. If you use arpd and modify it you can make it send you notifications on arp table changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to catch arp add/del messages.
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>


/* convert the netlink multicast group number into a bit map */
/* (  e.g. 4 => 16, 5 => 32  ) */
static __u32 nl_mgrp(  __u32 group  )
{
    if (  group > 31  )
    {
        printf(  "Netlink: Use setsockopt() for this group: %d\n", group  ) ;

        return 0 ;
    }

    return  (  group  ?  (  1 << (  group - 1  )  )  :  0  ) ;
}


void process_message(  char *buf ,  int raw_msg_len  )
{
    struct  nlmsghdr *nlmp ;
    struct  ndmsg *rtmp ;
    struct  rtattr *rtatp ;
    int     rtattrlen, len, req_len ;
    struct  in_addr *inp ;
    char    ipv4string[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] ;

    printf(  "process_message: raw_msg_len: %d\n" ,  raw_msg_len  ) ;

    for (  nlmp = ( struct nlmsghdr * ) buf ;  raw_msg_len  >  sizeof( *nlmp )  ;   )
    {
        int len = nlmp->nlmsg_len ;
        int req_len = len - sizeof( *nlmp ) ;

        //check if arp is changed
        if(nlmp->nlmsg_type == RTM_NEWNEIGH){
                printf("RTM_NEWNEIGH\n");
        } else if (nlmp->nlmsg_type == RTM_DELNEIGH){
                printf("RTM_DELNEIGH\n");
        }

        if (  ( req_len < 0 )  ||  ( len > raw_msg_len )  ||  ( ! NLMSG_OK(  nlmp, raw_msg_len  ) )  )
        {
            printf(  "error\n"  ) ;
            // Should processing of the message continue if there are certain types of problems?
        }

        rtmp = ( struct ndmsg * ) NLMSG_DATA(  nlmp  ) ;
        rtatp = ( struct rtattr * ) IFA_RTA(  rtmp  ) ;



        rtattrlen = IFA_PAYLOAD(  nlmp  ) ;

        for (  ;  RTA_OK(  rtatp, rtattrlen  ) ;  rtatp = RTA_NEXT(  rtatp, rtattrlen  )  )
        {
            if(  rtatp->rta_type == NDA_DST  )
            {
                inp = ( struct in_addr * ) RTA_DATA(  rtatp  ) ;
                inet_ntop(  AF_INET, inp, ipv4string, INET_ADDRSTRLEN  ) ;
                printf(  "addr: %s\n" , ipv4string  ) ;
            }
        }

        raw_msg_len -= NLMSG_ALIGN(  len  ) ;
        nlmp = ( struct nlmsghdr * ) (  (  char*  ) nlmp + NLMSG_ALIGN(  len  )  ) ;
    }

    // How is the event to be parsed?
}


int main(  int argc ,  char** argv  )
{
    int             sock ;
    static struct   sockaddr_nl g_addr ;
    char            buffer[4096] ;
    int             received_bytes = 0 ;
    int             ret ;

    /* Zeroing addr */
    bzero(  &g_addr, sizeof( g_addr )  ) ;
    g_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK ;
    g_addr.nl_groups = nl_mgrp( RTNLGRP_NEIGH ) ;

    if (  (  sock = socket( AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE )  )  <  0  )
    {
        printf(  "socket() error: %s\n", strerror( errno )  ) ;

        return -1 ;
    }

    if (  bind(  sock, ( struct sockaddr * ) &g_addr, sizeof( g_addr )  ) < 0  )
    {
        printf(  "bind() error: %s\n" ,  strerror( errno )  ) ;

        return -1 ;
    }

    while (  1  )
    {
        received_bytes = recv(  sock , buffer ,  sizeof(  buffer  ) ,  0  ) ;

        if (  received_bytes > 0  )
        {
            printf(  "\n- Event -\n"  ) ;
            process_message(  buffer, received_bytes  ) ;
        }
    }
}
```